# I am having trouble using Cramer's rule in a differential equations question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Let $a = 16$ and $b = 2$. Write the system in operator form and solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and solve using Cramer’s rule. Reconcile the constants. Solve for initial conditions $x(0) = 2, x(0) = 0$ and $y(0) = 0, y(0) = 0$. Graph these solutions for $t = 0 \ldots  40$ on the same axes. What is happening between pendulum $x$ and $y$?

I have set up the equations but I am stuck on how exactly to make Cramer's rule work. When I take the determinant of both sides I get $[(D^2+18)(D^2+18)-4]x=0$. I am unsure what to do next. Should I move the $4$ to the other side?

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset math on this site using mathjax/latex (it's really easy to learn).

Answer (score 1):

So far so good, there is no need to move the 4 to the other side. Next step is to apply the differential operators and solve the homogeneous differential equation that results from your determinant:

$\frac {d^{4}x}{dt^4}+36\frac {d^{2}x}{dt^2}+320=0$,

which gives us a general solution of the form:

$c_1\cos(2\sqrt5t) + c_2\sin(2\sqrt5t) +c_3\cos(4t) + c_4\sin(4t)$

From here you can repeat the process to get $y(t)$ and reconcile the constants.